# Assign a value to a node in the tree I'm processing

Tags: xslt, xpath

Using XSLT 1.0, I want to process four node sets, in order, A, B, C, D. But I can't specify each node set with a single (or at least not manageable) XPath expression.

I'd like to, right up front, sweep through and tag all the nodes I want to be A's, all the nodes I want to be B's, etc., and then later be able to select at will all A nodes, all B nodes, etc.

I also might want to add to the list later.

I can't create attributes in the file I'm processing. (Right?) Variables go out of scope too soon. Maybe something using keys? A key for all A's, all B's? But can I add more nodes to a key table once the key has been created?

Or is there a way to save XPaths?

Is there a straightforward way to do this, or must I just create a nasty, awful, error-prone, terrible-to-maintain Xpath expression every time I want to select each of my node sets?

Comment: Seems too generic -- are you expecting to learn all XPath and XSLT as the answer to a single question? If so, the best answer is: Get and read a good book about XSLT/XPath. Here are links to some of the best resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Comment: You're thinking in terms of a procedural solution to the problem, and you're getting frustrated because XSLT is a declarative language and doesn't allow a procedural solution. If you try to explain to us the problem you are trying to solve (instead of your procedural approach to solving it) then we might be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks Michael. In a client-side transformation, I process, in order, four node sets, each defined by a complex XPath expression. I need to process those same four sets several times while rendering the HTML. How can I avoid repeating the XPath expressions in my XSL each time I need to process the four sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Use Global Variables, like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="A" select="//tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:title" />
<xsl:variable name="B" select="//tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:author" />
<xsl:variable name="C" select="//tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:sponsor    | 
                               //tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:funder     | 
                               //tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:principal  | 
                               //tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:respStmt   |
                               //tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:editionStmt              |
                               //tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:extent                   |
                               //tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:seriesStmt" />
<xsl:variable name="D" select="//tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:notesStmt/tei:note" />
```

Then later:

```
<xsl:call-template name="writeMetadata">
   <xsl:with-param name="rowitems" select="$A" /> 
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="writeMetadata">
   <xsl:with-param name="rowitems" select="$B" /> 
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="writeMetadata">
   <xsl:with-param name="rowitems" select="$C" /> 
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="writeMetadata">
   <xsl:with-param name="rowitems" select="$D" /> 
</xsl:call-template>
```

repeated as often as needed, without needing to repeat the Xpath expressions.

(Michael, your comment "People often fail to realise that global variable definitions can reference the source document," posted at dpawson.co.uk, got me looking in the right area.)

Comment: Or add a key, which is also global and can be set with XPath queries into the tree. An example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703217.