# Most recent siblings back to some condition

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
<product id="456">
<product id="457" defective="yes">
<product id="458">
<product id="459">
<product id="460" defective="yes">
```

When the context node is product 460, I need to iterate through it and preceding-siblings back to (but not including) the last defective one. That is, I need a for-each on products 458, 459, and 460, but not 457 or before.

It can't be assumed that I got to the context node be iterating through all products in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPreceding" match="product" use=
 "generate-id(
     (self::product|following-sibling::product)
                           [@defective='yes'][1]
              )"/>

 <xsl:template match="product[last()]">
     <xsl:copy-of select="key('kPreceding', generate-id())"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML** (corrected to be well-formed !!!):

```
<t>
    <product id="456"/>
    <product id="457" defective="yes"/>
    <product id="458"/>
    <product id="459"/>
    <product id="460" defective="yes"/>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<product id="458"/>
<product id="459"/>
<product id="460" defective="yes"/>
```

**Explanation**:

Using a key for indexing any product by the `generate-id()` of the first following-sibling `product` that is defective (or self, if this `product` is defective itself).

Comment: Neat! I guess we just assume the processor will optimize that key creation so it doesn't become an n-squared problem.

Comment: The construction of an index is O(N) and then getting a value from the index is O(1) -- exactly as with any good hashtable implementation.

Comment: This also answers my earlier question about strategies for sweeping through and assigning values (such as "next defective product") to nodes. General strategy: don't assign values to the nodes; instead make key tables (or global variables) that include the values. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: I'd have thought "for each item, test all following siblings" would have made it n-squared. But that just shows I don't know anything about how to build indices efficiently! If you say it works, I'll believe you and use the construction. Thanks again. +1, Q answered.

Comment: @JPM: In the worst case the construction of the index could be O(N^2), but even then, the index is constructed only once and used many times. If the key would be used only once, then there is nothing to be gained using it. Also, do notice that there is significant difference in using `following-sibling::someName` and `following-sibling::someName[1]` . In the first case, all following siblings participate. In the second case, just the first immediate following sibling participates. The second case can be significantly faster than the first.